# Phonegap: force an app to quit instead of running in background

Tags: iphone, ipad, cordova, quit

I'm developing an iPhone/iPad application through Phonegap, is there a way to implement a sort of "click here to quit app"? I mean quit for real, not "put it in the background and go to home screen".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do this, your app will get rejected.

Answer (score 2):

you can use following code to quite your app on click,

```
device.exitApp()
```

OR

```
navigator.app.exitApp()
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks. All of the lecturing in the other answers is annoying; sometimes you DO need to let them exit.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to implement a sort of "click here to quit app"?'

Yes, there is a way for really exiting the app and killing its process.

***But never do that.*** Not only because Apple rejects your app if you do this. The problem with this is bad user experience. iOS is not a desktop operating system. You have a Home button for leaving apps (and again, there's a reason apps don't exit completely).

The window size is, conceptually, not spacious enough for maintaining an extraneous 44x44 pixel frame (44 pixel is the minimal size that can comfortably be touched, according to Apple's Human Interface Guidelines) dedicated only for exiting.

However, if you still want to exit after this lecture, there are several ways:

```
exit(0);
pthread_kill(pthread_self()); // on the main thread
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminateWithSuccess];
```

etc. Some of them may have a binding in PhoneGap (if not, it's easy enough to write one yourself).

Answer (score 1):

You should not do that as this may considered as violation of iOS Human Interface Guidelines, lead rejection of your app.

```
Always Be Prepared to Stop

**Save the current state when stopping at the finest level of detail possible so that people don’t
lose their context when they start the app again.** For example, if your app displays scrolling data,
save the current scroll position. To learn more about efficient ways to preserve and restore your
app’s state, see “State Preservation and Restoration”.
```

Apple guidlines link :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html

Answer (score 1):

in the application's plist put

```
 UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = TRUE
```

and when the user hits the home button, the application will quit.  No need for a button, no need for exit().

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23